# In the Opensearch Dashboards, How do I grant access to the Discover page without granting Admin access?

Tags: opensearch, amazon-opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I have an Internal user and want to grant them the ability to create dashboards and visualizations in Opensearch 9 (v 2.11.0).

The only way I've found to do this so far is to grant them the 'security_manager' role which is way too much access for what I'd like to give them.

Do I need to create a roll?  Is there an explicit permission to assign to that roll?  I have gone through the documentation and have yet to find a good resource that clearly explains which permissions are required for which pages/apps in the dashboards.

We are using the AWS managed service in case that matters.